# Running Protractor tests from Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor, jenkins

Usually, I used to run from command line (protractor `config.js`).
I used protractor and java script.

**PLS LET ME KNOW STEPS TO ACHIEVE RUNNING FROM JENKINS**

To run from Jenkins , I created a batch file `run.bat` containing (protractor `config.js`).

JENKINS:

```
New project ->config system -> Execute window batch command (run.bat)
```

ERROR:
I received following error after running my job-

```
Started by user aaaa
Building in workspace C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\Workspace
[Workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins483586556774856213.bat

C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\Workspace>call run.bat 

C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\Workspace>protractor config2.js 
'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\Workspace>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: well is the machine even windows?
and if it is, is there npm and protractor installed?

Comment: yes Windows, i have automated 150 testcases using protractor javascript. i run from webstorm, but i wanted the same to run from jenkins.

Comment: Have you setup the globally installed npm modules in the environment variable? For example, C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm in the Path environment variable in the 'System Variables' section. Jenkins is not able to identify your globally installed protractor module.

Comment: @Bhavani yes i do added. tried again , still same error

Comment: Forgot to mention. Please  can you restart your system once and retry to execute again.

Comment: You can have a look at this blog link for Jenkins plugin and try it: https://medium.com/@cnishina/protractor-in-ci-jenkins-6f5fd3fc06ee

Comment: I have installed protractor globally, even i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Jenkins workspace folder is not set , so it is running and trying to search project folders in temp file.First set the [workspace folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854377/how-to-change-workspace-and-build-record-root-directory-on-jenkins) for the job.

Also make sure 'Protractor' as a npm module is installed on the machine where execution is being performed.

1). First move to the project folder.

```
    cd C:\Project_RootFolder_Path
```

2).Install it globally.

```
npm install -g protractor
```

I would recommend to run in a more abstracted way using Gulp task.

Also if you are just calling protractor conf.js in your .bat file, you can directly put that line in 'Execute windows batch command' section in Jenkins.